# Generate Dataset from plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, dataset

Hello I have come across a problem where I need to generate dataset from a distribution given on a scatter plot where datapoints are mostly centred  around the centre of the circle and also surrounded within particular radius of the circle.Any ideas of generating such datasets in python ?

Answer (score 1):

One way of producing a distribution over a circular shape is to sample a one dimensional distribution and then stretch it over the 2 Pi circonference of a circle.

One could then decide to use a uniform or a normal distribution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dist(R=4., width=1., num=1000, uniform=True):
    if uniform:
        r = np.random.rand(num)*width+R
    else:
        r = np.random.normal(R, width, num)
    phi = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi, len(r))
    x= r * np.sin(phi)
    y = r* np.cos(phi)
    return x,y

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9,4))

ax[0].set_title("uniform")
x,y = dist()
ax[0].plot(x,y, linestyle="", marker="o", markersize="2")
x,y = dist(0,1.2, 400)
ax[0].plot(x,y, linestyle="", marker="o", markersize="2")

ax[1].set_title("normal")
x,y = dist(4,0.4, uniform=False)
ax[1].plot(x,y, linestyle="", marker="o", markersize="2")
x,y = dist(0,0.6, uniform=False)
ax[1].plot(x,y, linestyle="", marker="o", markersize="2")

for a in ax:
    a.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generalize random numbers with some distribution centered on a point, for example normal centered on the 0, 0.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', alpha=0.6)
```

[image: data example plot]

**EDIT:**

What we do is generate random points in polar coordinates. First we do a random for the angle (between 0 and 2 pi) and then we give the noise multiplying it by some random number.

```
n = 300
theta_out = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2*np.pi, size=n)

noise_out = np.random.uniform(low=0.9, high=1.1, size=n)

x_out = np.cos(theta_out) * noise_out
y_out = np.sin(theta_out) * noise_out

theta_in = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2*np.pi, size=n)

noise_in = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.5, size=n)

x_in = np.cos(theta_in) * noise_in
y_in = np.sin(theta_in) * noise_in

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')    

plt.plot(x_out, y_out, 'o')
plt.plot(x_in, y_in, 'o')
```

[image: final example]

Note that there is more density of points while the lower the radius.

Comment: @Hima Added to the answer!